# sapply 2 vectors

Tags: r

Let's say I have 2 lists

```
divisor = c(0, 1, 1, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9 )
remainder = c(99,  0,  1,  1, 99,  0,  1, 99,  0)
```

I want a divisor *element* to be *element + 1* if its corresponding remainder is NOT 0.
The final answer should look like:

```
updated.divisor = (1, 1, 2, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9)
```

How would I do this using `sapply`?

So far I have

```
sapply(remainder, function(x) {
    if x != 0{
       #divisor = divisor + 1
    }
    else{
       #divisor = divisor + 0
    }
}
```

P.S. I could probably use a nested loop but I want to be able to do this using `sapply`.

Comment: Your specified result required a NOT in the description sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To your comment: If you wanted an apply type solution you would use `mapply` because it allows you to process two arguments "alongside each other":

```
mapply( function(x,y) {x + !(y==0)}, x=divisor, y=remainder)
#[1] 1 1 2 8 8 8 9 9 9
```

An `ifelse` solution would make sense, too:

```
 ifelse(remainder !=0, divisor+1, divisor)
#[1] 1 1 2 8 8 8 9 9 9
```

Answer (score 11):

You don't need a loop:

```
divisor + (remainder!=0)
[1] 1 1 2 8 8 8 9 9 9
```

---

This is one of the most fundamental principles of R: all basic operations (and many functions) accept vectors as input and perform the operation on all elements of that vector at the same time.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks for the teaching me something new. If I did have to use sapply, how would I do that?

Comment: @user1342697 You would not use `sapply` on this example. That would just be a bad idea. If you have another problem where you think `sapply` is the right thing to do, then I suggest you post a new question.